# System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace error in C# for SSIS

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I am using the below code to write a ssis package in C# and when I write this code i get an error

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
    public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
    {

        public override void PreExecute()
        {
            base.PreExecute();
        }
        public override void PostExecute()
        {
            base.PostExecute();
        }
        string toreplace = "[~!@#$%^&*()_+`{};':,./<>?]";
        string replacewith = "";
        public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex(toreplace);
            Row.NaN = reg.Replace(Row.Na, replacewith);


        }

    }
```

The error is

```
The best overloaded method match for 
'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator)' has some invalid arguments
```

Here `Na` is the input column and `NaN` is the output column both are varchar with special characters in Inpout column.

Exceptions:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
System.ArgumentOutofRangeException
```

This is the code in the BufferWrapper in the SSIS package

```
/* THIS IS AUTO-GENERATED CODE THAT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN! DO NOT EDIT!
*  Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services buffer wrappers
*  This module defines classes for accessing data flow buffers
*  THIS IS AUTO-GENERATED CODE THAT WILL BE OVERWRITTEN! DO NOT EDIT! */



    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

    public class Input0Buffer: ScriptBuffer

    {
        public Input0Buffer(PipelineBuffer Buffer, int[] BufferColumnIndexes, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
            : base(Buffer, BufferColumnIndexes, OutputMap)
        {
        }

        public BlobColumn Na
        {
            get
            {
                return (BlobColumn)Buffer[BufferColumnIndexes[0]];
            }
        }
        public bool Na_IsNull
        {
            get
            {
                return IsNull(0);
            }
        }

        public Int32 NaN
        {
            set
            {
                this[1] = value;
            }
        }
        public bool NaN_IsNull
        {
            set
            {
                if (value)
                {
                    SetNull(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("IsNull property cannot be set to False. Assign a value to the column instead.");
                }
            }
        }

        new public bool NextRow()
        {
            return base.NextRow();
        }

        new public bool EndOfRowset()
        {
            return base.EndOfRowset();
        }

    }
```

Data flow

[image]

Script component, input columns

[image]

Script component, actual script

[image]

Comment: What is the Type of `Row.Na`?

Comment: I wonder how it will interpret a regex with `[]` inside of a `[]`. Somehow I don't think that will work as intended.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Na is a varchar type

Comment: What is CLR type of `Row.NA`?

Comment: @sircodesalot after removing [] from the replace selecction I get the above exceptions along with the error

Comment: `varchar` is not a `c#` type. What is the Type of `Row.Na`?

Comment: This code is written in C# for SSIS package in script component so this just fetches the row from the table in the database

Comment: You're not helping us to help you. let us know what is the type of `Row.Na` or just post that code too

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this is the whole code I have written in script component of SSIS package

Comment: Try this place mouse cursor over `Row.Na` press `F12` It will take you to `Row.Na` property. Check and let us know what is type of `NA`

Comment: NA is of type `BlobColumn` am not sure what is `BlobColumn` here. but you get error because you need to pass `String`. I mean `reg.Replace("somestring", replacewith);`. so change your code accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine. You are not testing for the possibility that the `Na` column is NULL. Perhaps your source data doesn't allow for nulls and thus, no need to test.

You can improve your performance by scoping the Regex at the member level and instantiate it in your PreExecute method but that's just a performance thing. Has no bearing on the error message you are receiving.

You can see my package and the expected results. I sent 4 rows down, one with a NULL value, one that shouldn't change and two that have changes required.

## My data Flow

I have updated my data flow to match the steps you are using in your chameleon question.

[image: data flow]

### My Source Query

I generate 2 columns of data and 4 rows worth. The Na column, which matches your original question is of type varchar. The column Agency_Names is cast as the deprecated Text data type to match your subsequent updates.

```
SELECT 
    D.Na
,   CAST(D.Na AS text) AS Agency_Names
FROM
(
SELECT 'Hello world' AS Na
UNION ALL SELECT 'man~ana'
UNION ALL SELECT 'p@$$word!'
UNION ALL SELECT NULL
) D (Na);
```

### Data Conversion

I have added a Data Conversion Transformation after my OLE DB Source. Reflecting what you have done, I converted my `Agency_Name` to a data type of `string [DT_STR]` with a length of 50 and aliased it as "Copy of Agency_Name".

[image: data conversion]

### Metadata

At this point, I verify that the metadata for my data flow is of type DT_STR or DT_WSTR which are the only allowable inputs for the upcoming call to the regular expression. I confirm that `Copy of Agency_Names` is the expected data type.

[image]

### Script Task

I assigned ReadOnly usage to the columns `Na` and `Copy of Agency_Name` and aliased the later as "AgencyNames".

[image]

I added 2 output columns: NaN which matches your original question and created AgencyNamesCleaned. These are both configured to be DT_STR, codepage 1252, length of 50.

[image]

This is the script I used.

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    string toreplace = "[~!@#$%^&*()_+`{};':,./<>?]";
    string replacewith = "";


    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(toreplace);

        // Test for nulls otherwise Replace will blow up
        if (!Row.Na_IsNull)
        {
            Row.NaN = reg.Replace(Row.Na, replacewith);
        }
        else
        {
            Row.NaN_IsNull = true;
        }

        if (!Row.AgencyNames_IsNull)
        {
            Row.AgencyNamesCleaned = reg.Replace(Row.AgencyNames, replacewith);
        }
        else
        {
            Row.AgencyNamesCleaned_IsNull = true;
        }
    }

}
```

### Root cause analysis

I think your core issue may be is that the `Na` column you have isn't a string compatible type. [Sriram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210181/system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace-error-in-c-sharp-for-ssis/18222568#comment26693167_18210181)'s comment is spot on. If I look at the autogenerated code for the column `Na`, in my example I see

```
    public String Na
    {
        get
        {
            return Buffer.GetString(BufferColumnIndexes[0]);
        }
    }
    public bool Na_IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return IsNull(0);
        }
    }
```

Your source system has provided metadata such that SSIS thinks this column is binary data. Perhaps it's NTEXT/TEXT or n/varchar(max) in the host. You need to do *something* to make it a compatible operand for the regular expression. I would clean up the column type in the source but if that's not an option, use a `Data Conversion` transformation to make it into a DT_STR/DT_WSTR type.

## Denouement

You can observe in the Data Viewer, attached to my first image, that NaN and AgencyNamesCleaned have correctly stripped the offending characters. Furthermore, you can observe that my Script Task does not have a red X attached to it as your does. This indicates the script is in an invalid state.

As you had created the "Copy of Agency_Names" column from the Data Conversion Component as DT_TEXT, wired it up to the Script Component, and *then* changed the data type in the Data Conversion Component, the Red X on your script might be resolved by having the transformation refresh its metadata. Open the script and click recompile (ctrl-shift-b) for good measure.

There should be no underlines in your `reg.Replace(...` code. If there is, there is another facet to your problem that has not been communicated. My best advice at that point would be to recreate a proof of concept package, exactly as I have described and if that works, it becomes an exercise in finding the difference between what you have working and what you do not have working.

Comment: Sorry for reopening but when I follow the above steps i am having the same error again i even converted the source data type to DT_WSTR

Comment: No worries. If it's not fixed, it's not fixed. Would you however, create a simple reproduction package as I have outlined above? Shouldn't take more than a few moments. I just want to verify you can do this successfully with the sample data I used.

Comment: Add new package. Add OLE DB Connection manager to any SQL Server instance you have handy. Add Data Flow. Inside Data Flow, add OLE DB Source and use the query in my screenshot `SELECT 'Hello world' AS Na`. Attach script task as described above. Add Derived Column after script task and put a data viewer on it.

Comment: Double click your blue line between Data Conversion and Script Component. Select Metadata tab and screen shot it, ensuring the definition for "Copy of Agency_Names" is completely visible

Comment: You are not using the Data Conversion task correctly. You need to actually change the data type of the `Agency_Names`. Currently, all you have done is made a copy of the same DT_TEXT column. Change this to a type of `String [DT_STR]`, length as appropriate, Code Page 1252. "Perhaps it's NTEXT/TEXT or n/varchar(max) in the host. You need to do something to make it a compatible operand for the regular expression. I would clean up the column type in the source but if that's not an option, use a Data Conversion transformation to make it into a DT_STR/DT_WSTR type"

Comment: Because you aren't using it correctly. You need to specify *what* you would like the new data type to be. The default data type, which you used, will match the source data. A DT_TEXT data type, despite having *TEXT* in the name, is not applicable for string based operations. You must convert it to a string based type: DT_STR or DT_WSTR.

Comment: Yes, that. Your data type is now something that the regular expression can handle.